# What are the default ports of ELK Stack services?

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the default port number of ELK Stack products? APM, Elasticsearch, Kibana, Logstash, and Beats?

Answer (score 19):

- APM: `8200` <sup>[apm](https://github.com/elastic/apm-server/pull/886/files)</sup>
- Elasticsearch: `9200`
- Kibana: `5601`
- Logstash: `5044`
- Beats are client libraries, so no port number.

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/elk/get-started/understand-default-config/

Comment: Logstash: 9600 (port for Logstash API )
Logstash: 5044 (port for Logstash Listener for Beats)

Comment: Beats -> Logstash Listener -> Logstash API -> ElasticSearch API -> Kibana